# Prove that $24|p^2-q^2$ where $p $ and $ q$ are primes $p>q>5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is my working

$p^2-q^2=(p+q)(p-q)$

As both the integers on right hand side are even .It is divisible by 4.

Primes are of form either $3k+1$ or $3k+2$ .we get 3 possible cases for for $p$ and $ q$
After substituting them we notice that it is also divisible by 3. It is divisible by both 4 and 3. Therefore it is also divisible by 12.But how to show that it is divisible by 24

Comment: Primes are of the form either $6k+1$ or $6k-1$

Comment: I tried it. It too gives me the same result

Comment: Not just primes.  Works for any products of such primes and also you can use $p,q\ge 5$.

Answer (score 1):

As $p$ is odd,
$$(p + q) + (p - q) = 2p \equiv \pm 2 \mod 4.$$
But if none of $p + q$ or $p - q$ was divisible by $4$, then we’d have
$$(p + q) + (p - q) \equiv (\pm 2) + (\pm 2) \equiv 0 \mod 4.$$
Remember that they both are even, being the sum of two odd numbers.

All in all, one of $p + q$ and $p - q$ must be divisible by $4$, the other still being even.

(With the same trick you get easily that $p^2 - q^2 \equiv 0 \mod 3$, as $1$ is the only nontrivial square modulo $3$ and $p$ and $q$ are not divisible by $3$.)

Answer (score 0):

$p=6k\pm1$ and $q=6m\pm1$ so

$p^2-q^2=(6k\pm1)^2-(6m\pm1)^2=(36k^2\pm12k+1)-(36m^2\pm12m+1)$

$=12k(3k\pm1)-12m(3m\pm1)$.

Now note that $2|k$ or $2|3k\pm1$ and same for $m$.

Comment: How did you deduce that k is even

Comment: $k$ is not necessarily even, but, if it is not, then $3k\pm1$ is, so in any event $k(3k\pm1)$ is even

Comment: When I searched this question in "question search bar" it said no results how can I find question to avoid being asking duplicate questions

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity:  that should be a comment on your question, not on my answer, or maybe you could ask on [Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions)