# If $p,q$ are primes, and $p>q>5$, prove that $240\vert p^4 - q^4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, divisibility

The source of the question is from 2019 UKMT Senior Maths Challenge, Further Investigation 1.6 :

**"If $p,q$ are primes, and $p>q>5$, prove that $240\vert p^4 - q^4$"**

I am struggling with the question , as I’m not too sure on the proof for this statement.

**My attempts :**

I do know that for when $p>q>2$, you can express the primes as $2x + 1$, where $x$ is a positive integer.
I also know that when $p>q>3$, you can express the primes as $6x\pm1$.  **However I’m unaware of a similar general formula for $p>q>5$ which is the reason I can not complete my work.**

$(p^4 - q^4) \implies (p+q)(p-q)(p^2+q^2)$,
Consider the case, where $p>q>2$
All numbers $p$ and $q$, can be expressed in the form 2n + 1.
$(p^2 + q^2) \pmod 2 \implies 0\pmod2$, $2\vert(p^2+q^2)$
With regards to $(p+q)(p-q)$, p and q can be $1\pmod 4$ or $3\pmod4$, therefore $8\vert p^2 - q^2$.
This implies $16\vert p^4 - q^4$, when $p>q>2$

Now consider the  where, $p>q>3$
All prime numbers can be expressed in the form $6n \pm 1$, following from the first case, we know $2\vert p^2 + q^2$
With regards to $(p+q)(p-q)$, p and q can $1\pmod 6$ or $5\pmod6$, therefore $12\vert (p+q)(p-q)$.
Knowing that $16\vert p^4 - q^4$ for $p>q>2$ we can take the lowest common denominator of 16 and 12, to get $48\vert p^4 - q^4$, when $p>q>3$

The reason why I don't know how to prove p>q>5, because I'm not aware of a standard form for all prime numbers greater than 5, (I used 2n+1, for primes greater than 2, and $6n\pm1$ for primes greater than 3).

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3401118/prove-that-24p2-q2-where-p-and-q-are-primes-pq5?noredirect=1).

Comment: $p^4-q^4=(p-q)(p+q)(p^2+q^2)$, which of those is divisible by $2$, $3$, $4$ and/or $5$? Just combine everything and you'll end up with the requested result.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  Starting with $m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)$ seems like a good idea.

Comment: Already solved at [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1939836p13352769).

Comment: Give me like 30 minutes I’ll try to get it done.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I have done an edit adding MathJax and tidying up the question so it looks more presentable.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I already did. But I used this to denote divisibility instead: $\vert$.

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "**Your question should be clear without the title.**
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: Using the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) makes this trivial since $\lambda(240) = 4$

Answer (score 2):

Sufficient to show that $~p^4 - q^4~$ is divisible by each of $~16, ~5,~$ and $~3.$

From the constraints :

- $~p = q + 2k ~: ~k \in \Bbb{Z^+} \implies $ 
  $p^4 - q^4 = 8kq^3 + 24k^2q^2 + 32k^3q + 16k^4.$ 
  So, divisibility by $~16~$ is determined by whether 
  $~kq^3 + k^2q^2~$ must be divisible by $~2.~$ 
  If $~k~$ is even, both numbers are even, and if $~k~$ is odd, both numbers are odd.
- From [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $~p^4 \equiv 1 \equiv q^4 \pmod{5} \implies 5 ~| ~(p^4 - q^4).$
- From [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), $~p^2 \equiv 1 \equiv q^2 \pmod{3} \implies p^4 \equiv 1 \equiv q^4 \pmod{3} \implies $
  $3 ~| ~(p^4 - q^4).$

Answer (score 1):

We have $240=2^4\cdot 3\cdot 5$, by CRT we only need to check that $p^4-q^4$ is divisible by each prime power.

> **Modulo $2^4$**

> We have $x^8\equiv_{16}1$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z_{16}^\times$ since $\phi(16)=8$. However, $\Bbb Z_{16}^\times\cong\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_4$ so we have $$x^4\equiv_{16}1$$ Therefore $p^4-q^4\equiv_{16}0$

> **Modulo $3$**

> We have $x^2\equiv_31$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z_3^\times$, so $$p^4-q^4\equiv_3(p^2)^2-(q^2)^2\equiv_30$$

> **Modulo $5$**

> We have $x^4\equiv_5 1$ for all $x\in\Bbb Z_5^\times$, so $$p^4-q^4\equiv_5 1-1\equiv_5 0$$

Comment: Sorry, but I’m unfamiliar with the set of integers, z, being superscripted with an x and subscripted with 10 in your very first spoiler. Care to explain what that is?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_{16}$ is the set (ring) of integers modulo $16$, that is, $$\Bbb Z_{16}=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\}$$ $\Bbb Z_{16}^\times$ is the set (ring) of units in $\Bbb Z_{16}$, the integers that have a multiplicative inverse. Thus $$\Bbb Z_{16}^\times=\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\}$$

Comment: Is the units of z_16, the same as the odd numbers of  z_16?

Comment: Yes! $\Bbb Z_{2^n}^\times$ always consists of only the odd numbers. These are the only ones who do not share a factor with $2^n$ (for $n\geq 1$). But this is only true for powers of $2$.

Comment: Perhaps a clearer way to get the $\bmod 16$ result is by binomial expansion. Each of $p,q$ will have the form $4x\pm 1$ and $(4x\pm 1)^4=(4x)^4\pm 4(4x)^3 + 6(4x)^2 \pm 4(4x) +1$ which is plainly $\equiv 1 \bmod 16$

Answer (score 1):

### Elementary Way :

**(A)** Consider that all Primes larger than $5$ are ODD
Hence , each of the $3$ factors $(P+Q)$ , $(P-Q)$ , $(P^2+Q^2)$ are EVEN , hence , we have got $2 \times 2 \times 2 = 2^3$

Now , $P$ can be $4X+1$ or $4X-1$ , while $Q$ can be $4Y+1$ or $4Y-1$.
When both $P$ & $Q$ have the $+1$ form or both $P$ & $Q$ have the $-1$ form, then $(P-Q)$ is not just EVEN , it is a multiple of $4$.
When one has the $+1$ form while the other has the $-1$ form , then $(P+Q)$ is a multiple of $4$.
Hence , we have got one more $2$ factor to get $2^4$

**(B)** Consider that all Primes larger than $5$ are of the form $3X+1$ or of the form $3X-1$
When both $P$ & $Q$ have the $+1$ form or both $P$ & $Q$ have the $-1$ form, then $(P-Q)$ is a multiple of $3$.
When one has the $+1$ form while the other has the $-1$ form , then $(P+Q)$ is a multiple of $3$.
Hence , we have got $3$ factor

**(C1)** Similarly , when we take the Primes larger than $5$ to be like $5X+1$ or $5X-1$ , then either $(P+Q)$ or $(P-Q)$ will be a multiple of $5$.

**(C2)** When we take the Primes larger than $5$ to be like $5X+2$ or $5X-2$ , then either $(P+Q)$ or $(P-Q)$ will be a multiple of $5$.

**(C3)** When $P$ is like $5X+1$ or $5X-1$ , while $Q$ is like $5X+2$ or $5X-2$ (or vice-versa) , then $(P^2+Q^2)$ will be a multiple of $5$.

All Cases , we have got factor of $5$.

### SUMMARY :

Over-all , we have the factors $2^4,3,5$
Hence , $240$ is a factor.

### ADDENDUM :

We do not have to use the $6N+1$ form , though that will give slight variation in the Proof , which could get a little longer when we want the factor of $5$.
**It is easier when we use multiple forms , which are suitable to get each factor.**